# Add Formatting Buttons to Gutenberg core/paragraph BlockControls

Tags: block-editor

When inserting a core/paragraph block to the content, we can choose e.g. "bold", "add link" from the controls above the content:

[image]

For my customer, I would like to add formatting buttons for `<sup></sup>` and `<sub></sub>`, in order to make it possible to write simple chemical or mathematical formulas, e.g. CO2 or m2.

I tried something like this, with a filter (taken from [here](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit)):

```
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const { InspectorControls, BlockControls } = wp.editor;
const { PanelBody, Toolbar } = wp.components;

const withInspectorControls =  createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockControls>
                    // what should I enter here?
                </BlockControls>
                <BlockEdit { ...props } />
            </Fragment>
        );
    };
}, "withInspectorControl" );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'my-plugin/with-inspector-controls', withInspectorControls );
```

a) how can I add the required buttons in the filtered `<BlockControls>`?

b) is this the right approach?

**Update 2019-01-24**

An official tutorial is now available [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/docs/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/format-api). I haven't tried it yet, but it seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The tutorial works. Unfortunately, the added button is in a dropdown at the end of the formatting toolbar. If there's an easy way to make it visible immediately, that would be terrific.

Answer (score 3):

An official tutorial to add custom buttons is now available [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/docs/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/format-api).

**Update August 2023**

The mentioned tutorial no longer exists - try [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-controls-toolbar-and-sidebar/#block-toolbar) instead.

Comment: you mean, it **was** available there...

Comment: Added new link to get you - hopefully - on the right track

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, and assuming you haven't now discovered this already, this plugin might be helpful / provide you what you need:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-rich-text-tools/

If you want to build it yourself, then the source code for this plugin might also be instructive https://github.com/iseulde/advanced-rich-text-tools/blob/master/sub-sup.js and will demand you using the new (Gutenberg) Format API.