# Gutenberg custom block: RichText underline button

Tags: block-editor

I am working on a custom block for Gutenberg and part of this block is a RichText component. I am trying to add a button that underlines the text and I cannot make it work since last night. The code I have now [does not work]:

```
<div>
            <BlockControls
                controls={ [
                    {
                        icon: 'editor-underline',
                        title: __( 'Underline' ),
                        onClick: () => {
                          console.log(this.test.current, this)
                            this.test.current.props.onChange(toggleFormat(
                              this.test.current.props.record,
                                { type: 'core/underline' }
                            ) );
                        },
                    },
                ] }
                />
              <RichText
                  tagName="p"
                  label="Intro"
                  className={ className }
                  multiline="br"
                  ref={this.test}
                  value={ content }
                  formattingControls={[]}
                  onChange={ ( content ) => { this.props.setAttributes( { content } ) } }
              />
            </div>
```

Can you help me on working this thing out?

Comment: toggleFormat is from import { toggleFormat } from '@wordpress/rich-text';

Answer (score 0):

In a block that I am currently trying to build I am using a RichText control.

This has buttons/menu items for Bold, Italic, Code, Link, Inline Image and Strike though.

Though there isn't a button for underlining the text I can just use the key command [cmd+U] and it underlines.

This seems to work and is saved on the frontend and backend.

If it was working. There could be a few issues why it has stopped. Have you any errors in the console?

Have you tried removing the block and re-adding it?

EDIT: I am a beginner with Gutenberg block development so I am out of my depth!

You might find this useful if you haven't already come across it.

[Add Formatting Buttons to Gutenberg core/paragraph BlockControls](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320570/add-formatting-buttons-to-gutenberg-core-paragraph-blockcontrols)

Comment: cmd+u works, but the client wants a button